# Configure an action to execute on every user input

Tags: bash, shell, unix, terminal, cygwin

So far I've been only using aliases and functions defined at `.bashrc` file, but now I need to know how to configure a function to run before/after every command I make. How can I achieve it?

Comment: PS1 for before the command, PROMPT_COMMAND for after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an environment variable `PROMPT_COMMAND`, see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-PROMPT_005fCOMMAND)

> `PROMPT_COMMAND`
>
> If set, the value is interpreted as a command to
>   execute before the printing of each primary prompt (`$PS1`).

For a trivial case, set it like an alias:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo "Something"'
```

For more complex stuff, you can have it call a function:

```
prompt_command () {
    # If username has underscore, shorten to 'a_b'; else just use first letter
    un="${USER:0:1}"
    if [[ $USER == *?_?* ]]; then
        local suff="${USER##*_}"
        un+=_"${suff:0:1}"
    fi
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command
```

I use this to modify the username in my prompt, so elsewhere in my `.bashrc` there is something like

```
export PS1="$un@\h \$"
```

The typical `user@host $` prompt thus, but the username is dynamically shortened as specified in the `PROMPT_COMMAND` function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `PS4` trick of doing same. Assuming you want to run `date` command before each command then you can set `PS4` as:

```
PS4='$(date)\n'
```

Then just enable to trace to start printing date before each command:

```
set -x
```

Then you can see date appearing before each command is executed:

```
$> set -x

$> tty
Fri May 27 09:57:42 EDT 2016
tty
/dev/ttys004

$> uname
Fri May 27 09:57:48 EDT 2016
uname
Darwin
```

If you want to turn this off just turn off the trace using:

```
set -x
```